# Vim Fugitive: toggling ":Gblame" function

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

I'm still kinda new in vim so i hope this question isn't too basic, but I couldn't find an answer in fugitive's DOCs..
im looking to add a toggling function that does the following:

```
if :Gblame buffer is open:
     close buffer
else 
     execute "normal :Gblame<CR>"
endif

map gb :call (the above function)<CR>
```

I was thinking of adding a variable that changes between 1 or 0 depending on the number of times i used the "gb" mapping.
But what i would really want is a way to check if the buffer is open. is that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Fugitive plugin sets a custom `'filetype'` in the sidebar blame buffer (to `fugitiveblame`; queried via `:setlocal filetype?`, or in Vimscript via the `&l:filetype` special variable). This only works when you're currently in the sidebar. To make this work for the main window, too, you'd have to check for the buffer name (e.g. via `bufwinnr('fugitiveblame') != -1`), and then also go back to that window before calling `:close` (or using `:bdelete` with the buffer number obtained via `bufnr('fugitiveblame')`).

```
function! s:ToggleBlame()
    if &l:filetype ==# 'fugitiveblame'
        close
    else
        Gblame
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap gb :call <SID>ToggleBlame()<CR>
```

#### Notes

- `:Gblame` is a (custom) Ex command; you can just invoke it as-is in Vimscript; no need for `:normal` here.
- Closing the sidebar is just `:close` when you're in it, as mentioned above.
- I've defined a *script-local function*; cp. [`:help <SID>`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3CSID%3E).
- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Comment: Might want to use `:normal gq` inside the `fugitiveblame` window as it will close the blame window and then restore the file to the working tree (like `:Gedit`). See `:h fugitive-:Gblame`. However, I think I would just make a mapping to `:Gblame` and learn to use `gq` inside the blame window.